# Depth pass stencil shadows with old gl

Tags: c, opengl

I am trying to implement depth pass stencil shadows. 
The project I am working now pure old gl so I can't use shaders etc.. 
I found a great [example](http://joshbeam.com/articles/stenciled_shadow_volumes_in_opengl/) which I am trying to move to my project. 
But instead depth fail I am trying depth pass shadows now.

```
    glCullFace(GL_FRONT);
    glStencilFunc(GL_ALWAYS, 0x0, 0xff);
    glStencilOp(GL_KEEP, GL_KEEP, GL_DECR);-->Decrease the stencil buffer 
    render_surface_shadow_volume(c->surfaces[i], c->position, light_pos);

    glCullFace(GL_BACK);
    glStencilFunc(GL_ALWAYS, 0x0, 0xff);
    glStencilOp(GL_KEEP, GL_KEEP, GL_INCR); ---> Increase the stencil buffer 
    render_surface_shadow_volume(c->surfaces[i], c->position, light_pos);
```

And below using the stencil test to replace fragments which are not equal to zero.

```
    glStencilFunc(GL_NOTEQUAL, 0x0, 0xff);
    glStencilOp(GL_REPLACE, GL_REPLACE, GL_REPLACE);
    draw_shadow();
```

My first question why
 glStencilOp(GL_REPLACE, **GL_REPLACE**, **GL_REPLACE**); why last two parameters are GL_REPLACE  instead GL_KEEP shouldn't be all about stencil fail instead depth fail?

More important question what I have is having a shadow volume even all I want is shadow on the surface.
[image: having a shadow volume]